# How do we delete all the bookmarks with label : MyBookmarkList

Tags: google, google-bookmarks

Google Bookmarks had recently merged all the bookmarks in lists as bookmarks with labels `MyBookmarkList`.

How do we search for (and delete) all bookmarks that have the label `MyBookmarkList`, yet have no other labels besides that?

Searching for `label:MyBookmarkList` doesn't work because it returns bookmarks that belong in the other labels as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Bookmarks search cannot exclude "all other labels"](http://support.google.com/bookmarks/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180158). You can refine your searches multiple times by adding `-label:whatever` to your original query `label:MyBookmarkList`.

Nonetheless, there are a few caveats to bookmark management:

1. You can't perform batch operations on bookmarks
2. Labels remain in your list as long as there's at least 1 tagged bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

To delete any label, including MyBookmarkList, go to the google bookmarks page:
https://www.google.com/bookmarks/

Scroll to the bottom and click on the "Manage labels" link.
You can then click on the Remove link next to the label you no longer want.
This will remove the label from all the bookmarks which have that label, in one step.

Comment: No it is not the label(s) that I wanted to remove, it is the bookmarks. I wanted to remove the bookmarks *with* that selected label, that has no other accompanying label.